# The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'.

```
void getData({
    required String url,
    required Map query,
  }) {
    dio.get(
      url,
      queryParameters: query,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your `Map` type parameters explicitely:

```dart
//                                             vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
void getData({required String url, required Map<String, dynamic> query}) {
  dio.get(url, queryParameters: query);
}
```